# Eliminate the char's in url strings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

i am new to iphone. i want to eliminate chars from %0A onwards in below url string and %20 also.please any one give some solns.

case:1

http://www.sampleurl.com-feb
1.2161280%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20

case:2

%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20http://www.sampleurl.com-feb.html%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20

in case 2 also, want to eliminate chars before and after url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your strings look like they are url encoded and contain whitespace at the beginning and end.

```
NSString* decodedString = [myString stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSString* cleanedString = [decodedString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Now `cleanedString` is what you are looking for.